# Threejs zooms out the model in the scene and the shadows get weird

Tags: three.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yj1NI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myvEu.png)
Why is that?

https://threejs.org/editor/

Answer (score 0):

This is due to multiple light sources in the scene. They are all casting shadows through different angles, which is why you see this.

Comment: When I created it, the shadow showed its correct shape, and when I made it smaller, the shadow shape was different from the original shape of the object